# PHP+Mysql Order by id does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am building a blog system and I am stuck with a particular problem for days now trying hard to solve and also making necessary research but to no avail.

Below is my current script

```
include('../php_includes/connect3.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,entry FROM usersexpressfeelings WHERE id = '$requiredID'");
            //$unique_user_expressions = $_SESSION['username'];
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array(($result), MYSQL_ASSOC )):
            $post_ID = $row["id"];
            $entry = $row["entry"];
            $edited_area = $entry;

        ?>
            <form action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" class="how_do_i_feelForm" id="">

                <textarea  class="textarea" placeholder="how do you feel " name="expression" id="">
                    <?php echo $edited_area; ?>
                    <?php ?>
                </textarea>

                <span><input type="submit" class="" name="update" id="" value="Express feeling" /></span>
            <?php endwhile; ?>  
            </form>

             <div><?php if(isset($errormessage)) {echo $errormessage;}?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to be able to select a unique user, by using respective unique id from the database and update it. Unfortunately, my code does not return the unique id(post) but displays all the posts made by the user.

Not sure what is going wrong.Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html `SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]` <=

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will check it out as soon as possible

Comment: `$requiredID = 100; $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,entry FROM usersexpressfeelings  WHERE id=$requiredID ");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just use a WHERE clause and its displaying only one static post for all.What could be wrong now?

Comment: Try adding a GROUP BY

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tried it and now nothing is displaying

Comment: Are you not echoing? There's nothing to support that in your *posted* code/question.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Please wrap everything in backticks, because you are using a protected mysql variable: "SELECT \`id\`, \`entry\` FROM \`userexpressfeelings\` WHERE \`id\` = '$requiredID'"

Comment: hey @DuncanWoode so what is your `$requiredID` value??? :-) what is going wrong now? `action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` just change to `action=""`

Comment: not working now. I will surely get it done and post the correct working code for you to also see.

Comment: @KimAlexander@Fred-ii-...It's working now very much well. The problem was I forgot to get the ID of the entry I needed to update. Where could I post the correct working code so you could also see  and if any further advice I would appreciate alot